# Adding alpha band to a TIFF image drastically increases its filesize?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, transparency-opacity, multi-band

I'm using `gdalwarp -dstalpha src.tif dst.tif` to add alpha channel to an 8-bit unsigned image with 3 bands. The initial size of the image is 300 mb, but adding an alpha band increases it to 1980 mb, which is far more than expected 1/4 increase.

What is the matter?

Comment: The original image is probably compressed and you write out an uncompressed image. Check with gdalinfo and use suitable -co compress= option.

Comment: Could you please provide your full gdalwarp call?

Comment: Yeah that is my concern.  If his gdalwarp call involved clipping (instead of simply adding an alpha band) it will result in file inflation, which as you mention is duplicate.

Comment: @onakua I don't think it matters, solution is the same: `gdalwarp -of VRT -dstalpha src.tif dst.vrt && gdal_translate -co compress=whatever dst.vrt dst.tif`